# Interesting scroll behaviour when scrolling past end

Tags: codenameone

I created a form to check the effect of margin and padding on a scrollable component. Apparently padding is part of the scrolling content - which I didn't find documented anywhere. 
Should one reasonably be able to guess or should this be documented?

Anyway - there is a strange behaviour when scrolling down the list past its end where I would have expected it to scroll back to content just like tensile scrolling, but it doesn't. Is it a bug?

The attached code demonstrates this - the +-button adds buttons to the list; the down-button scrolls to the last entry - when clicked the list is in a weird condition:

```
public class FormMarginPaddingScroll extends Form {
    private int entrytally = 0;

    public FormMarginPaddingScroll() {
        setTitle("FormMarginPaddingScroll");
        setScrollable(false);
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        contentPane.setScrollableY(true);
        Style style = contentPane.getAllStyles();
        style.setMarginUnit(Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS, Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS, Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS, Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS);
        style.setMargin(5, 5, 5, 5);
        style.setPaddingUnit(Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS, Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS, Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS, Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS);
        style.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        style.setBorder(Border.createDashedBorder(1));
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea("This form is for checking margin, border, padding and scrolling behaviour.");
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        contentPane.add(textArea);
        {
            FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = FloatingActionButton.createFAB(FontImage2.MATERIAL_ARROW_DOWNWARD);
            floatingActionButton.bindFabToContainer(contentPane, Component.LEFT, Component.BOTTOM);
            floatingActionButton.addActionListener((e) -> scrollDown(contentPane));
        }
        {
            FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = FloatingActionButton.createFAB(FontImage2.MATERIAL_ADD);
            floatingActionButton.bindFabToContainer(contentPane, Component.RIGHT, Component.BOTTOM);
            floatingActionButton.addActionListener((e) -> newEntry(contentPane));
        }
    }

    private void scrollDown(Container contentPane) {
        Component componentLast = contentPane.getComponentAt(contentPane.getComponentCount() - 1);
        contentPane.scrollRectToVisible(
                componentLast.getX(),
                componentLast.getY(), 
                componentLast.getWidth(), 
                contentPane.getHeight(), 
                componentLast);
    }

    private void newEntry(Container contentPane) {
        final int entryid = ++entrytally;
        Button button = new Button("" + entryid);
        button.addActionListener((e) -> {
        ToastBar.Status status = ToastBar.getInstance().createStatus();
        status.setMessage("button " + entryid + " pressed");
        status.setExpires(3000);
        status.show();
        });
        contentPane.add(button);
        contentPane.revalidate();;
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding more than one FloatingActionButton also does not behave well. They seem to group somehow.

Comment: Did you tried to revalidate the Container after adding Components?

Comment: I changed the code and invoke `contentpane.revalidate()` now after adding a button. That doesn't seems to make any difference.

Comment: Padding is generally a part of the Component space it's behavior with the scrolling of components is mostly an implementation detail since we default to 0 padding/margin on containers. As far as I understand the problem is because of the padding you've set to the content pane? If you remove that everything works? What did you try to accomplish with the padding?

Comment: I was trying to understand what is going on with scrolling. In particular I am interested in preventing misbehaviour when a scrollable container contains resizeable elements. Everything works fine when a scrollable container is larger than its visible size and it is growing. But you get unpleasant effects when a scrollable container shrinks. I thought to place an invisible component at the end of the container, or perhaps use padding.

Comment: Removing the padding doesn't change anything.